# Is there a way for UI Testing the Framework Code in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ui-testing

Is there a way for UI Testing the framework code by adding it in a iOS application and getting the code coverage? If yes, let me know please.

Comment: Looks like XCode bug to me. Please check the below link https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/96314#96314